# Python HMAC / Encoding in 3.x vs 2.x

Tags: python-3.x, signature, amazon-mws

I'm working with code that works in Python 2.7, but when I use it with 3.6, it doesn't work. It's meant to encode a signature for an Amazon MWS API call.

The original code in Python 2.7:

```
sig_encoded = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(str(self.secret_key), sig_data, hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

I read a few other posts here, followed the instructions, and came up with this:

Python 3.6

```
    key_enc = (bytes(self.secret_key, "utf-8"))
    sig_data_enc = (bytes(sig_data, "utf-8"))
    sig_encoded =  base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key_enc, sig_data_enc, hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

However, this returns an error from the API. What is wrong with the version used in Python 3.6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find the answer. The code that works in Python 3.6 is:

```
return base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(str(self.secret_key).encode('utf-8'), sig_data.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
```